# Swift - Load/Parse JSON file

Tags: json, swift, parsing

**I have this json file:**

```
{
  "fields": {
    "123456": {
      "timestampValue": "2019-03-05T23:00:00Z"
    },
    "7895": {
      "timestampValue": "2019-03-02T23:00:00Z"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2019-03-08T00:14:55.357221Z",
  "updateTime": "2019-03-08T17:22:08.398718Z"
}
```

**and I need to get this values:**

```
"123456"   "timestampValue": "2019-03-05T23:00:00Z"
"7895" "timestampValue": "2019-03-02T23:00:00Z"
```

**There is my Code in DataLoader.swift file:**

```
import Foundation

public class DataLoader
{
    @Published var userData = [UserData]()

  init()
  {
    load()
    //sort()
  }

  func load()
  {

    if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mydata", withExtension: "json")
    {
      do
      {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)

        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode([UserData].self, from: data)
        self.userData = dataFromJson  
      }
      catch
      {
        print(error)
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

**There is my code in UserData.swift file:**

```
import Foundation

struct UserData: Codable
{

    var timestampValue: Date = Date()
    var fields: String

}
```

**And there is a error :**

typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
[]

Many thanks for some help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root is a dictionary not an array here `[]` in `[UserData]` indicates array  You need

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let fields: [String: Field]
  let createTime, updateTime: String
}

// MARK: - Field
struct Field: Codable {
  let timestampValue: String
}
```

---

```
let dataFromJson = try jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer but I get this error now ->
typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "fields", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "104428", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "timestampValue", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
Root

Comment: change `let timestampValue: String`

Comment: It's working thanks, 
but how I can put Id value's into variables?
etc.: "123456"

Comment: add another question and clarify exactly what you need and share link here for specific help

Comment: Hi there is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60621264/create-variables-from-parsed-json-file-to-tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Object: Codable {
    let fields: [String: Field]
    let createTime, updateTime: String
}

struct Field: Codable {
    let timestampValue: Date
}
```

use it like this

```
let object = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: jsonData)
```

use do catch for safety

```
object.fields.forEach { field in
    field.timestampValue
}
```