# Create variables from parsed JSON file to tableView

Tags: swift

**I have this printed output from parsed JSON file:**

```
[App.Root(fields: ["12345": App.Field(timestampValue: "2020-02-04"), "7895": App.Field(timestampValue: "2020-02-04")], createTime: "2020-02-04", updateTime: "2020-02-04")]
```

**There is my code from UserData.swift file:**

```
import Foundation

struct Root: Codable {
  let fields: [String: Field]
  let createTime, updateTime: String
}

// MARK: - Field
struct Field: Codable {
  let timestampValue: String
}
```

How can I create variable for etc.:Id 12345?

I need to put it in tableView in this format:

```
ID:12345
Date:2020-02-04

next row in table view:
ID:7895
Date:2020-02-04

Many thanks for some suggestions :)
```

Comment: Can you provide some code where you're parsing the JSON data?

Comment: Hi there is:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603297/swift-load-parse-json-file

Comment: So you're retrieving the data from an API? right?

Comment: No from local JSON file

Comment: @Marek If you can post the JSON response/model , that would be great to understand. Your codable models also need some clean up.

Comment: Can you provide that JSON file? Or if there is any sensitive info, do you mind PMing me it?

The thing is that your `struct` is wrong. And we will need to look at the JSON file to help you futhur

Comment: {
  "fields": {
    "123456": {
      "timestampValue": "2019-03-05T23:00:00Z"
    },
    "7895": {
      "timestampValue": "2019-03-02T23:00:00Z"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2019-03-08T00:14:55.357221Z",
  "updateTime": "2019-03-08T17:22:08.398718Z"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let res = try jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
var all = [Item]()
for (id,item) in  res.fields {
  all.append(Item(id:id,timestampValue:item.timestampValue))
}
```

---

```
struct Item {
   let id,timestampValue:String 
}
```

Then use `all` as table dataSource array

Comment: I get: Use of unresolved identifier 'fields'
in this line: for (id,item) in  fields {

Comment: First question yes :D
but 2nd invoke...table cell

Comment: Just place the `all = [Item]()` right below your class. And use that array for the tableview, just like @Sh_Khan explained. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60630961/parsed-value-from-array-not-displayed-in-tableview