# Parsed value from array not displayed in tableview

Tags: swift

I need to display value -> "all[0].id" into table row.
This value is id 123456 from JSON file.
Code builded without errors, but still without data in table row.

thanks for some suggestions
I parsed JSON File with this values:

```
    {
  "fields": {
    "123456": {
      "timestampValue": "2019-03-05T23:00:00Z"
    },
    "7895": {
      "timestampValue": "2019-03-02T23:00:00Z"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2019-03-08T00:14:55.357221Z",
  "updateTime": "2019-03-08T17:22:08.398718Z"
}
```

There is my ViewController file with tableview:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
let data = DataLoader().userData
let all = [Item]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return all.count
    }

          func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
       cell.textLabel?.text = all[0].id

        return cell
       } 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()       
       tableView.dataSource = self   
       tableView.delegate = self   
 }      
}
```

There is my Code in DataLoader.swift:

```
public class DataLoader
{
    @Published var userData = [Root]()

  init()
  {
    load()

  }

  func load()
  {

    if let fileLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mydata", withExtension: "json")
    {
      // Do catch in case of error
      do
      {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let res = try jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
     var all = [Item]()
      for (id,item) in res.fields {
      all.append(Item(id:id,timestampValue:item.timestampValue))

     }
       print(all)      
      }
      catch
      {
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is there in the item? Is it empty? What is the count of the item? Also, write `viewLifeCycle` methods above the `delegate` methods. To clean things you can use an `extension`.

Comment: Hi, in item is 12345 and item count is 2

Comment: Can you show me where have you added in the `item`?

Comment: import Foundation




struct Root: Codable
   
{
 let fields: [String: Field]
 let createTime, updateTime: String
}

 //MARK: - Field
struct Field: Codable
{
 let timestampValue: String
}

struct Item {
   let id,timestampValue:String
}

Comment: No, I meant where have you added the values in this? Just print `all` and let me know.

Comment: print(all)
output:
[App.Item(id: "12345", timestampValue: "2020-02-04"), App.Item(id: "7654", timestampValue: "2020-02-05")]

Comment: Please edit the question and provide the **real** code. The code in the question will never display anything.

Comment: Hi sry,I edited it

Comment: If I'm not missing it, your "all" is just constant empty array defined like "let all = [Item]()". You're loading data into totally different array which is defined as local variable "var all = [Item]()".